# GPU or display defect?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, gpu

My MacBook Pro 13" (A1502, early 2015) is displaying a flickering screen with horizontal lines and all kinds of other distortions.

An external monitor hooked up by HDMI works just fine though without any artifacts even in mirror mode.

Can I regard this as **hard evidence** that the GPU is not defective? (And by that it's probably the macbook display that needs to be replaced)

Comment: Might be the connector cable to the screen. You'd need a service tech to look at it.

Comment: Do you mean the connector cable from the lcd to the motherboard? I dis- and reconnected that one already, no luck